# How to ignore system font size and font style in android

Tags: android

How to ignore font size and font style entire application android I used below code but not working

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
}
```